# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (same shape)

Tags: python

I am getting an error about broadcasting an input array from shape. Normally, this seems to be caused by converting some array of dimension `p` into some array of dimension: `p+1` or `p-1`. However, the shapes of my input and output seems to be the same: 3 dimensions. So my question is, what am I doing wrong and how do I go about addressing this issue?

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e821b7e8e0de> in <module>()
    108                   "overlay_glasses.shape: ", overlay_glasses.shape)
    109 
--> 110             overlay_img[int(y):int(y+h),int(x):int(x+w)] = overlay_glasses
    111
```

The following are the output of print statements, to give a better understanding of the above code.

```
'overlay_img.shape: '    , (365, 365, 3), 
'overlay_glasses.shape: ', ( 34,  99, 3)
'x: ', 623.26, 'y: ', 265.9
'h: ', 34, 'w: ', 99
```

larger code snippet:

```
[omitted code here]
if len(centers)>0:
    # change the given value of 2.15 according to the size of the detected face
    glasses_width = 2.16*abs(centers[1][0]-centers[0][0])
    overlay_img = np.ones(shape = roi_color.shape,
                          dtype = np.uint8)*255
    h,w = glass_img.shape[:2]
    scaling_factor = glasses_width/w
    overlay_glasses = cv2.resize(src           = glass_img,
                                 dsize         = None,
                                 fx            = scaling_factor, # scale factor along x-axis; when it equals 0, it is computed as \texttt{(double)dsize.width/src.cols}
                                 fy            = scaling_factor, # scale factor along y-axis
                                 interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) # INTER_AREA: resampling using pixel area relation. It may be a preferred method for image decimation,

    x = centers[0][0] if centers[0][0] < centers[1][0] else centers[1][0]

    #   The x and y variables  below depend upon the size of the detected face.
    x   -=  0.26*overlay_glasses.shape[1]
    y   +=  0.85*overlay_glasses.shape[0]
    print("x: ", x,
          "y: ", y)

    #slice the height, width of the overlay image.
    h,  w   =   overlay_glasses.shape[:2]

    print("h: ", h,
          "w: ", w)

    print("overlay_img.shape: ", overlay_img.shape,
          "overlay_glasses.shape: ", overlay_glasses.shape)

    overlay_img[int(y):int(y+h),int(x):int(x+w)] = overlay_glasses # this is the offending line of code
```

Comment: Try printing the shape of `overlay_img[int(y):int(y+h),int(x):int(x+w)]`.

Comment: What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: You can't fill up `(34, 0, 3)` with `(34,  99, 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` is out of range to create a subimage for the `overlay_img` you have provided. The dimensions of your image are (365, 365, 3), but you provide `x` to be 623 and `x+w` to be 722. This creates an empty subimage which cannot be filled with the `overlay_glasses`'s contents. Obviously there is something wrong with the `x` coordinate.